# Speck cipher implementation in C - Test vector Error

Tags: c

I implemented the SPECK cipher 64/96 in C.

Encryption and decryption are operating well, I think.

However, when I check the test vector in a paper, my implementation is wrong.
(The paper is [The Simon and Speck Families of Lightweight Block Ciphers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404.pdf) — there may be other sources for it.)
I don't know where I have mistakes.

What have I missed?

My implementation is:

```
#define ROR(x, r) ((x >> r) | (x << (32-r)))
#define ROL(x, r) ((x << r) | (x >> (32-r)))
#define ROUNDS 26
#define u32 unsigned int

void Speck64Encrypt(u32 ct[], const u32 pt[], const u32 K[]){

    u32 i;
    u32 L[ROUNDS + 1] = { 0, };
    u32 RK[ROUNDS] = { 0, };

    RK[0] = K[0];
    L[0] = K[1];
    L[1] = K[2];

    for (i = 0; i < ROUNDS - 1; i++)
    {
        L[i + 2] = (RK[i] + ROR(L[i], 8)) ^ i;
        RK[i + 1] = ROL(RK[i], 3) ^ L[i + 2];
    } // Round Key Generation!!!

    ct[0] = pt[0];
    ct[1] = pt[1];

    for (i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        ct[1] = (ROR(ct[1], 8) + ct[0]) ^ RK[i];
        ct[0] = ROL(ct[0], 3) ^ ct[1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    u32 k[3] = { 0x13121110, 0x0b0a0908, 0x03020100 };
    u32 pt[2] = { 0x74614620, 0x736e6165 };
    u32 ct[2] = {0, };

    Speck64Encrypt(ct, pt, k);
    printf("Expect : 0x9f7952ec, 0x4175946c\n");
    printf("Result : %08x, %08x \n", ct[0], ct[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What have I missed?" do you have a 16-bit `unsigned?

Comment: I find my problem. My problem is order of testvector... T.T
Thanks!!! 
Change the order, then testvector is:
        u32 k[3] = { 0x03020100, 0x0b0a0908, 0x13121110 };
        u32 pt[2] = { 0x736e6165, 0x74614620 };
I can confirm it!!

Answer (score 1):

You have entered the words of key and the plaintext backwards.  You should have K0=03020100, K1=0b0a0908, K2=13121110.  Also, pt1=74614620, pt0=736e6165.

Comment: 11 hours before you answer, Hoo posted the same in the comments: I find my problem. My problem is order of testvector... T.T Thanks!!! Change the order, then testvector is: `u32 k[3] = { 0x03020100, 0x0b0a0908, 0x13121110 };` `u32 pt[2] = { 0x736e6165, 0x74614620 };`

Comment: @sg7 Frankly answers shouldn't be written in the comments section, even by the author, as one may easily miss/ignore them (especially if they're hidden).